# Are the resolutions against the Iran missile program legal?

Tags: international-law, iran

There are resolutions against Iran missile program. Are these resolutions legal? Or is an article specifically preventing Iran? Doesn't any country have the right to develop their own defense system?

Comment: You keep using the word "defense" about ballistic missiles. [I do not think it means what you think it means](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YIP6EwqMEoE)

Comment: It is Iran's **"deterrence power"**. If not why other countries has this right? US missile  system is more destructive. what they want to do with that missiles?

Comment: One should think that any country has the right to defend itself , so nothing is wrong with Irans Missile program. I cannot remember that Iran acted aggressively against any other country since the Islamic revolution. Iran did not invade any other country or bomb the infrastructure of any other country to pieces, or kill thousands of civilians, shell schools and hospitals to the ground like some other countries did and do, to whom  we in the West happily sell our sophisticated weapons. Nothing seems wrong with this.

Comment: The resolutions  are just another means to try to sanction Iran's economy, restrain technical, scientific development and give the people a hard  time.

Comment: @user1 Of course the fact that Iran is saying that it will use these missiles to destroy those it defines as "enemies" (anyone who object to Iran's supporting terrorism around the world) triggers the resolutions. Since they are basically opinions being expressed, then they are legal anywhere "freedom of speech" is regarded as a right.

Comment: @sabbahillel Noor's comment is an answer to yours. Why dont you devolope the comment as an answer?

Comment: @sabbahillel Did you noticed this statement that American and Israeli officials repeat : ["**all options are on the table**"](http://www.theatlantic.com/international/archive/2012/08/what-all-options-are-on-the-table-with-iran-actually-means/260928/)? So UN must have sanctions against  America and Israel?

Comment: @user1 They are already trying to destroy the US and Israel because those two insist on actually trying to defend themselves against terrorism.

Comment: @user1, I think it would only be "defense" if the missiles were part of an anti-missile system. Nuclear missiles only have one purpose, and countries that have not proven they can be responsible with them must be evaluated critically. See this answer I made to another question for an explanation as to why people are worried: http://politics.stackexchange.com/a/8052/4482

Comment: But then what you say about: Saudi Arabia, Israel, U.S,...? they not only not proved they are responsible, but even proved they are **not** responsible; The reasons are Yemen, Palestine, and Hiroshima.  `Who give weapons to Saudi Arabia? the same who give sanctions to Iran.`  + Iran is under complete inspections (specially after "Joint Comprehensive Plan of Action"). It is obvious now that has not nuclear weapon.

Comment: "There are resolutions against Iran missile program." Since the implementation of the JCPOA in January 2016, there hasn't been any active UN Security Council resolutions actually prohibiting Iran from launching ballistic missiles. Resolution 2231 only says Iran is "called upon" not to undertake such ballistic missile activities that can be used to deliver nuclear weapons.

Comment: the part "such ballistic missile activities that ***can be used*** to deliver nuclear weapons" of your comment is not true. It should be "such ballistic missile activities that ***designed*** to deliver nuclear weapons"

Answer (score 1):

International politics are not governed by laws, so no action by a state can be definitely legal or illegal. It's in the subjective opinion of each government which actions by other governments they condone or support. International politics is basically anarchy. No country is bound to any rules they didn't agree to. You can claim that when a country breaks an agreement they signed they are breaking common law tradition, but I am not aware of any international agreements which guarantee Iran the right to own weapons of mass destruction.

When you look at [the list of UN resolution concerning Iran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_Nations_resolutions_concerning_Iran), then these resolutions are "legal" simply because they went through the normal UN processes and weren't vetoed by any of the veto-powers. Still, they are only effective as long as all the UN members enforce them.